# How to get/isolate the p-value from 'AnovaResults' object in python?

Tags: python, object, statsmodels, anova, p-value

I want to use one way repeated measures anova in my dataset to test whether the values of 5 patients differ between the measured 3 days.

I use AnovaRM from statsmodels.stats.anova and the result is an 'AnovaResults' object.
I can see the p-value with the `print()` function but i don't know how to isolate it from this object.

Do you have any idea? Also is my code correct for what i want to test?

Thanks in advance

```
day1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
day2 = [2,4,6,8,10]
day3 = [1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5]
days_list = [day1,day2,day3]

df = pd.DataFrame({'patient': np.repeat(range(1, len(days_list[0])+1), len(days_list)),
                   'group': np.tile(range(1, len(days_list)+1), len(days_list[0])),
                   'score': [x[y] for y in range(len(days_list[0])) for x in days_list]})

print(AnovaRM(data=df, depvar='score', subject='patient', within=['group']).fit())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the `p` value you're looking for is the number displayed in the `Pr > F` column when you run the code in your question. If you instead assign the results of the test to a variable, the underlying dataframe can be accessed through the `anova_table` attribute:

```
results = AnovaRM(data=df, depvar='score', subject='patient', within=['group']).fit()
print(results.anova_table)
```

which gives:

```
       F Value  Num DF  Den DF  Pr > F 
group  15.5     2.0     8.0     0.00177
```

Just access the 0th member of the `Pr > F` column, and you're all set:

```
print(results.anova_table["Pr > F"][0])
```

This yields the answer:

```
0.0017705227840260451
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Though i found i way i posted on the previous comment, i think your way is better! Can you comment your thoughts on my way?

Comment: Your method is rather roundabout, converting to HTML then back from it. Since you can access the underlying DataFrame in the `AnovaResults` object directly, that's probably the better way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a way!

```
a=AnovaRM(data=df, depvar='score', subject='patient', within=['group']).fit().summary().as_html()
pd.read_html(a, header=0, index_col=0)[0]['Pr > F'][0]
```

Hope it will help someone!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).